# What does this mean when I try to post a question?

Tags: support

we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.

Comment: should go to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory -- until you have a reputation of 10 here, you can only post 1 link per question.  Also, this belongs on meta.

Answer (score 2):

It means exactly what it says.  The only term that might be foreign is *reputation*, and the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) explains that (about halfway down the page).

Spammers thrive on getting things for free, so if you make them work a little (i.e. get 10 reputation points by answering a question and getting upvoted), they will go away.

Answer (score 1):

In an effort to keep people from just posting questions with links to their website in them, new users are not allowed to put more than one link in their questions.

Feel free to just post the URL in your question until you get enough reputation to post more.  One of the more experienced users will most likely edit your question to make it an actual link for you.

Comment: Back when I had a lowly 0 rep it didn't even allow me to post the URL as a non hyperlink.